# Rendering Bottom Menus in all Screens in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am facing a problem with react bottom navigation.I am tryig to figure out how I can pass the bottom navigation menu to all the screens.Based on the code below, all the screens within the navigation stack are okay.

```
const BottomNavigation = () => {

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator 
    tabBar={props => <MenuTab  {...props} />}

    screenOptions={{
      animation: 'slide_from_right'
  }}
                  initialRouteName="Home"
                  tabBarOptions={{
                  labelStyle: {fontSize: 12, marginTop: 5, fontWeight: 'bold'},
                  activeTintColor: "#5575DF",
                  inactiveTintColor: "#9e9e9e",
                  activeBackgroundColor: "#e5cfff",
                  }}

    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeTab}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused, color}) => (
              <TabBarIcon
                  focused={focused}
                  tintColor={color}
                  name="home-outline"
              />
          ),

      }}
    
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="One"
        component={One}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused, color}) => (
              <TabBarIcon
                  focused={focused}
                  tintColor={color}
                  name="calendar-outline"
              />
          ),

      }}
    
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Two"
        component={Two}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused, color}) => (
              <TabBarIcon
                  focused={focused}
                  tintColor={color}
                  name="wallet-outline"
              />
          ),

      }}
      
      />
      
      <Tab.Screen
      name="Three"
      component={Three}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color }) => (
          <TabBarIcon
            focused={focused}
            tintColor={color}
            name="menu-outline"
          />
        ),
      }}
    >
    </Tab.Screen>
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default BottomNavigation;
```

What should I do to pass the bottom menu to a screen called AnotherScreen when its opened.I dont want to include it as a menu item in the bottom navigation menu.

```
<NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Onboarding">
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Onboarding"
            component={SplashScreen}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Bottom"
            component={BottomNavigation}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="AnotherScreen"
            component={AnotherScreen}
            options={{
              headerShown: true,
            }}
          />
          
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Login"
            component={LoginScreen}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Signup"
            component={SignUpScreen}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          />

          <Stack.Screen
            name="Forgotpassword"
            component={ForgotPassword}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          />

      
        
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Show Bottom Tab**

React navigation docs [Hiding tab bar in specific screens](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/)
 shows in an example, How to show and hide bottom tab bar on screens,
Consider the following example

```
function HomeStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStack} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

With this structure, when we navigate to the `Profile` or `Settings` screen, the tab **bar will still stay visible** over those screens.

**Hide Bottom Tab**

When passing a component in BottomTab `"Home", "One", "Two", etc`. you have to pass `Stack` instead of `Single Screen`.

For example, In bottom tab

```
<Tab.Screen
     name="Home"
     component={HomeStack}
  ...  
/>
```

and `HomeStack` will consist of both screen component, i.e. `HomeScreen`, `AnotherScreen`